# !grepl in for loop to remove rows from a dataframe

Tags: r

I want to use a for loop to remove any row that contains a text string of values in another vector. I know I can use regex, but this is a process I repeat regularly, so I want to pass a vector of terms into a loop and then a larger function to save time.

```
# Dataframe that always changes
keyword <- c('acme regulator','regulator','brand regulator')
position <- c(1, 23, 3)

# Terms I want to remove that always change
rmterms <- c('acme','brand')

t_allkwsum <- data.frame(keyword, position)

df <- for (i in 1:length(rmterms)){
     x <- t_allkwsum[!grepl(rmterms[i],t_allkwsum$keyword),]
     df2 <- rbind(df2,x)
     }
```

df returns as NULL. I want it to return any row where an 'rmterms' value isn't present in t_allkwsum$keyword.

Comment: `t_allkwsum[!grepl(paste(rmterms, collapse = '|'), t_allkwsum$keyword), ]` is this the return you want

Comment: What is the expected output is still not clear.

Answer (score 0):

```
df[-which(rowSums(sapply(rmterms,
function(t,df){!grepl(pattern = t,x = df$keyword)},df))!=length(rmterms)),]

#keyword position
#2 regulator       23
```

Answer (score 0):

Not so clear what you want as an output. But, if you would like to keep the structure of the code you have provided, you could just use `if condition` in the `for loop` like below which would return you a row where an 'rmterms' value isn't present in 't_allkwsum$keyword'.

```
keyword <- c('acme regulator','regulator','brand regulator')
position <- c(1, 23, 3)

# Terms I want to remove that always change
rmterms <- c('acme','brand')

t_allkwsum <- data.frame(keyword, position)

list1 <- list()
j = 0
for (i in 1:length(rmterms)){
   if (grepl(rmterms[i],t_allkwsum$keyword) == FALSE) {
      j = j + 1
      list1[[j]] <- t_allkwsum[i,]
   } 
}
df2 <- do.call(rbind, list1)

df2
keyword position
2 regulator       23
```

However, I do not think using conditional and for loop is good idea computational wise.

Answer (score 0):

In dplyr version:

```
t_allkwsum %>% filter(!grepl(paste(rmterms, collapse="|"), keyword))
```